# MPDF Security : How to Prevent Convert PDF to Word?

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

I tried to make secure PDF from HTML using MPDF.

All the guide I found is only to put password to PDF file so user without password can't open it.

I want to set these setting using MPDF

[image]

**How do I  set PDF security using MPDF but still allowing user to view the file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mPDF method [`setProtection()`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setprotection.html).

Its first parameter is an array of features you want to allow. If you pass an empty array:

```
$mpdf->setProtection(array());
```

none of available features will be allowed.

Possible names of the features are

```
copy
print
modify
annot-forms
fill-forms
extract
assemble
print-highres
```

Second parameter of the method is a password you would pass if you wanted the file to be password-protected.